# Jupyter notebook consumes hard disk memory

Tags: python, memory-management, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I used to write many codes (in Python) in different cells in jupyter notebook, and run them once. I use also this command `%store` to store variables and other data structures, however I noticed that each time I execute them, the memory space of HDD is decreasing, that means that there are something is caching each time.
I tried unsuccessfully to reset it by `%reset -f`.

How can I remove all the cached data ?

Comment: The phrase “memory space of HDD” does not make sense.  The HDD is the disk where data is written for persistent storage (e.g. your files and Python install).  Memory is temporary storage (i.e. RAM).  I presume your memory usage (RAM usage) is high; not that your disk space is being eaten up.  Yes?

Comment: @S3DEV Thanks. No, I mean the HDD not the RAM

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved simply by restarting the computer, however I still need to some techniques to totally clear the temporary data upon each execution.